# js: add element at the start of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let´s say I have this array:
`let array = ["somevalue", "anothervalue"]`
So what I wanted to da was to add a value, for example:
`let foo = {bar: true}` and add this value at index 0, but not overwrite the old value, rather kind of 'push' the rest of the values back. I´ve heard of `array = [foo, ...array]` but I am not quite sure what it does and how and when to use it.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

```
let arr = [1,2]
let foo={bar:true}
arr=[foo].concat(arr)
```

also what you already know works

```
arr=[foo, ...arr]
```

That's it

Answer (score 4):

```
let array = ["somevalue", "anothervalue"]
let foo = {bar: true}
array.unshift(foo);
console.log(array); // prints [{bar: true}, "somevalue", "anothervalue"]
```

Similarly, the shift() method removes the first item in the array.

Answer (score 2):

It simply append the foo in front of array. so array will become

```
[{bar: true}, "somevalue", "anothervalue"]
```

Alternate :

You can also use unshift, it also append data at index 0, eg.

```
let array = [2, 3, 4]
array.unshift(1)
console.log(array) /// output : [1, 2, 3, 4]
```